# NSNumberFormatter with number style NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle trouble with commas

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nsnumberformatter, currency-formatting

I'm trying to do things right with input expenses on some items. So, when working on a device using a locale that uses comma separated decimals (the **decimal pad automatically** sets comma ',' instead of dot '.' **for the user to input**) I store the value using core data in a double variable converting the text this way:

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[f setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSNumber * gasto = [f numberFromString:(((UITextField*) [cell viewWithTag:11]).text)];
destino.nuevaTrans.gasto = [gasto doubleValue];
//destino.nuevaTrans is the managed object, nothing weird there, just storing the decimal value
```

But when taking the value out of the stored objects and showing them in a table view I'm losing the decimals because of the comma separated locale settings (?). Doing it this way:

```
etiq = (UILabel*) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:12];
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
etiq.text = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(trans.gasto)];

//debugging console output:
//remmember, trans.gasto is only a double
NSLog(@"a: %f, b: %@", trans.gasto ,[numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(trans.gasto)]);
```

The output on the simulator that is using dot '.' locale settings works fine, but when deploying on the device that is using comma ',' settings the NSNumberFormatter doesn't seem to translate it correctly to currency style.

```
//output on the simulator:
2014-09-07 15:00:47.561 iSpend[3930:60b] a: 2.990000, b: $2.99

//output on the device:
2014-09-07 15:02:40.005 iSpend[1389:60b] a: 2.170000, b: ₡2
```

So, I could try and hack this thing out... But I'm looking for a better programming practice here. Every suggestion is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried: `- (void)setMinimumFractionDigits:(NSUInteger)number` for the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Locale determines if it shows cents or just Krona. So, if you want to force it to show digits after the comma, add the line:

```
[numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
```

to get two digits after comma.

But the example you show has correct output.

Comment: You are right, thanks! Didn't thought of specifying the minimum amount of fraction digits as I had to on the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

u can try to set separator clearly: `[formatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."];`